# VBS script to connect to Microfocus ALM is not working

Tags: vbscript, alm

Am trying to connect to ALM from VBS code and get the list of test cases under the particular test set. But the connection is always not succesfull. Please help me with the code for this.
Am using the below code where am creating the the user input box to get the user name

```
Const QCDOMAIN = "TT20_UAT"
Dim QCConnection
Const QCPROJECT = "DVP"
Const QCSERVERURL = "https://microfocus-alm.srv.volvo.com/qcbin"
Const QCTestPathFrom = "Subject\UAT_Regression_Automation\Content Regression List\"
QCUSER = InputBox("Enter your Application Lifecycle Management (ALM) VCN user:","MasterScript for Regression Automation, step 1 out of 6","")
If QCUSER = vbEmpty Then
    Call CancelMessage
End If
QCPASSWORD = "xxxxxxx"

Set QTP = CreateObject("QuickTest.Application")
Set QCConnection = QTP.TDConnection
QCConnection.Login QCSERVERURL, QCDOMAIN, QCPROJECT, QCUSER, QCPASSWORD, False
If Err Then
    Call ErrorMessage("QUALITY CENTER USER OR PASSWORD IS INCORRECT.")
End If
```

Comment: what alm version are u using?

Comment: We are using web application not sure what is the version

Comment: Are you familiar with the "Generate Script" option in UFT? In UFT enter all the required information to Connect to ALM. Then I believe it is Under Setting, you should be able to generate the script. 
Also make sure you have the OTA client installed on the local machine